# if user enter 5 then display the last 5 elements of linked list vise versa

Tags: c++, linked-list

i am stuck in my uni assignment....

i have an linked list of 20 elements, i have to take the value from user and if user enter 5 then print the last 5 elements of linked list

```
void traverse(List list) {
    Node *savedCurrentNode = list.currentNode;
    list.currentNode = list.headNode;
    
    for(int i = 1; list.next() == true; i++)
    {
            std::cout << "Element " << i << " " << list.get() << endl;
    }
    
    list.currentNode = savedCurrentNode;
}
```

im trying this but this method prints all the elements of my linked list

Comment: So, find the length of the list, keep a count of where you are in the list (you already have that in the variable `i`) and only print the elements that are five or less away from the end of the list. For example if your list has a length of 20, then only print the elements where `i > 15`.

Comment: And if this is the task, it would make sense to track the size as a member variable. Incrementing appropriately for any function that adds to the list and decrementing for any function that erases. With the proper set-up, this should be a trivial task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void traverse(List list, int printFrom)
{
    Node *savedCurrentNode = list.currentNode;
    list.currentNode = list.headNode;
    
    for(int i=1; list.next(); i++)
    {
        if(i > printFrom)
        {
            cout << "Element " << (i - printFrom) << " " << list.get() << endl; 
        }
    }
    
    list.currentNode = savedCurrentNode;
}
```

### solved my prblem by this there printFrom is a variable whose value is number of elemenets that skipped like if my linked list have size of 20 and user want to see last 5 then printFrom stores 15 and skipped 15 values and print last 5

Answer (score 1):

For what little code you have, a review:

```cpp
// Why are you passing the list by value? That is wasteful.
void traverse(List list) {
    // I don't see you taking a value anywhere; surely you know how to do that

    // What is happening here? Can't you just assign the head to something
    // directly?
    Node *savedCurrentNode = list.currentNode;
    list.currentNode = list.headNode;
    
    // Like you said, this traverses the entire list, it's also poorly
    // formed. You literally don't need i.
    // for (; list.next(); /* However your list increments here */)
    for(int i = 1; list.next() == true; i++)
    {
            std::cout << "Element " << i << " " << list.get() << endl;
    }
    
    // What is the purpose of this?
    list.currentNode = savedCurrentNode;
}
```

For someone who is writing a linked list, this code seems to be fundamentally flawed. My expectation of someone tackling a linked list is that they are about to stop being a beginner, but I'm not seeing that here in the code and what structure of the list class is implied. The list class is *weird* to say the least.

And just to be clear, my expectation stems from where I place the linked list assignment in my curriculum. It's also more idiomatic than this list.

With that out of the way, this task is trivial **if** you took the time to think the project through. Most students skip the planning step and create unnecessary headaches for themselves.

Knowing that you would need the total size of the list, why not just make it member data? Any function that adds to the list will increment the value accordingly. And any function that subtracts from the list will decrement accordingly. That way you always know the size of the list at all times.

Knowing the size of the list is most of the battle. You then need to do the arithmetic necessary to advance in the list to satisfy your requirement. And now you can print.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class SList {
 public:
  SList() = default;

  //
  // Rule of 5 intentionally left out
  //

  void push_front(int val) {
    m_head = new Node{val, m_head};
    ++m_size;  // The magic happens here
  }

  std::size_t size() const { return m_size; }

  void traverse_last(int numElements, std::ostream& sout = std::cout) const {
    int placement = m_size;
    Node* walker = m_head;

    // Move our walker node the appropriate amount of steps
    while (walker && placement > numElements) {
      walker = walker->next;
      --placement;
    }

    // Now that we're in position, we can print
    while (walker) {
      sout << walker->data << ' ';
      walker = walker->next;
    }
    sout << '\n';
  }

 private:
  struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next = nullptr;
  };

  Node* m_head = nullptr;
  std::size_t m_size = 0ULL;
};

int main() {
  SList test;

  for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i) {
    test.push_front(i);
  }

  std::cout << "Size: " << test.size() << '\n';

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    test.traverse_last(i);
  }
  test.traverse_last(10);
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
Size: 5
5 
4 5 
3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```